# scheme calculating combination nCk using memoization

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I am trying to calculate how combination nCk using memoization in racket/scheme

I can't use separate recursive method to calculate n!. 
I have done this far, but saying this is bad syntex
i actually fixed bad syntex error!
but still gets an error in (let ([ans (assoc (x y) memo part!.
anyone know what i have done wrong?

```
 (define combm
  (letrec ([memo null]
           [f (lambda (x y)
                (let ([ans (assoc (x y) memo)])
                  (if ans
                      (cdr ans)
                      (let ([new-ans (letrec ([fac (lambda (x)
                                      (if (eq? x 0)
                                          1
                                          (* x (fac (- x 1)))))])
                        (/ (fac x) (* (fac y) (fac (- x y)))))])
                        (begin
                          (set! memo (cons (cons (x y) new-ans) memo))
                          new-ans)))))])
    f))

                                     `
```

Answer (score 1):

This expression `(assoc (x y) memo)` is the cause of the arror.

If you apply `combm` as in `(combm 42 43)` then `(assoc (x y) memo)` becomes
`(assoc (42 43) memo)`. And the `(42 43)` means "apply the value 42 on 43". The problem is that 42 is not a function.

Try `(assoc (list x y) memo)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution, which memoizes the factorial function:

```
(define combm
  (let ((memo '()))
    (lambda (n r)
      (letrec ((fact (lambda (n)
                       (let ((ans (assoc n memo =)))
                         (if ans
                             (cadr ans)
                             (if (< n 2)
                                 1
                                 (let ((res (* n (fact (sub1 n)))))
                                   (set! memo (cons (list n res) memo))
                                   res)))))))
        (/ (fact n) (* (fact r) (fact (- n r))))))))
```

The memoization is necessary for the factorial since it is used more than once in the formula for the combinatorial.

Comment: Thank you, i figured mine out as well.